# Can a different service solve my elastic search use cases for cheaper?

Tags: elasticsearch

I use elastic search to:

- Search for items by name
- Search for items that are hats
- Search for items that aren't hats
- Combos of the above

My data looks like this:

```
{
        "id": string,
        "name": string,
        "owner_user_id": number,
        "moderation_status": string,
        "component_keys": ["Hat", "Clothing", "Render"] # There are hundreds of unique values here
}
```

My cluster has 104 shards and only uses 93 MB of memory.

I'm a hobby developer, and Elastic is my highest operating expense right now.

Comment: U can run a single node Elasticsearch cluster with just 1 GB of heap size as well, you need to provide more information on you Elasticsearch cluster and why you are using 104 shards ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch cost depends on the multiple factors, like memory, disk, instance type and number of nodes in the cluster. And Elasticsearch cluster can have minimum 1 to no upper limit specified by Elasticsearch.

In your case I can see you have very less memory footprint so you can simply create a single node Elasticsearch cluster(if you are not using it for production use-case), and just assign the heap memory to 1 GB, this should solve your cost issue.

Apart from that curious to know why you have 104 shards, better to delete the unused shard to claim even more memory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure how to delete shards, as its controlled my Elastic Search. "Solving" the cost issue puts it at 100 dollars a month. Hard to stomach when my dynamo db usages for more data costs <20 bucks a month.

Comment: @OliverBarnum 100 $ per month is huge, what about the other details, like number of nodes in Elasticsearch cluster and instance type as mentioned you can simply run in to t4g.small instance which would cost less than 10$ per month according to EC2 calculator https://calculator.aws/#/createCalculator/EC2

Comment: Im running this off of elastic searches website cloud.elastic.co, not hosting it myself. Would you suggest that for tiny amounts of data?

Comment: @OliverBarnum why not when you are paying too much for such a small usage and its not that overhead to manage a small cluster

Comment: @OliverBarnum its been really long, please accept my answer if it helped you :)